# Actionscript regular expressions

Tags: regex, actionscript

I have written the following regular expression:

```
 [\s\S]*?,[\s\S]*?,(?P<lat>[\s\S]*?),(?P<long>[\s\S]*?)
```

In java it worked like a charm.
But when i use it in AS3 like this:

```
var pattern:RegExp = [\s\S]*?,[\s\S]*?,(?P<lat>[\s\S]*?),(?P<long>[\s\S]*?);
```

it gives an error...
I thought regular expressions where language independent...
Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say that worked in Java?  I don't think so.  Java does support named groups as of version 7, but it uses the simpler `(?<name>...)` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I **believe** you need to add `/` delimiters to the front and back side of you regex.

What is an example string you are trying to use, and what is the desired output?

And what is the error you get?